# ChatGPT integration with Django for parallel connection

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm using Django framework to have multiple ChatGPT connection at same time but it's make complete code halt/down until ChatGPT response is back.

To encounter this I'm using async with Django channels but still its block Django server to serve any other resource.

This is command to run Django server:

```
daphne --ping-interval 10 --ping-timeout 600 -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 backend.gradingly.asgi:application
```

this is code which is calling ChatGPT:

```
model = "gpt-4-0314"
thread = threading.Thread(target=self.call_gpt_api, args=(prompt,model,context,))
thread.start()
```

This is Python code which is sending response to channels

```py
async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
  f'user_{context["current_user"]}',{
    "type": "send_message", "text": json.dumps(json_data)
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

in case you want to use async I suggest flow this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/async/) which is about **Asynchronous support in Django** and it's configurations.

the other solution is to use background processing like **[celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html)** to task your connection with ChatGPT and run them in the background and you response the requests after they sent to background, not to wait for the results of ChatGPT. this [link](https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/) would be a good tutorial to use Celery and Django.